# If $f$ is an isometry between open sets, is $\left|\det{\rm D}f\right|=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, determinant, orthogonality, isometry, frechet-derivative

Let $d\in\mathbb N$ and $\Omega_i\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open.

If $f$ is an isometry from $\Omega_1$ to $\Omega_2$, can we conclude that $f$ is Fréchet differentiable and $\left|\det{\rm D}f\right|=1$? On the other hand, if $g$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $\Omega_1$ onto $\Omega_2$ with $\left|\det{\rm D}g\right|=1$, does $g$ need to be an isometry?

I'm unsure how to approach this. I know that if $h:\mathbb R^d\to\mathbb R^d$ is a *linear* isometry, then it is clearly Fréchet differentiable with ${\rm D}h=h$. Moreover, $h$ is orthogonal and hence $\left|\det{\rm D}h\right|=\left|\det h\right|=1$.

Comment: for the question about g the answer is no. Think of a linear transformation such as $g(x, y) =(cx, y/c)$ for $c>1$. For $f$ I don't know off the top of my head (but if f is defined on all of Rd then being an isometry means it is a translation along with an orthogonal linear map so the answer in this case is yes)

Comment: One can look at the change of variables formula in integral, that is , for any set $V$, $m(V) = \int_{V} 1 dx = \int_{f^{-1} (V)} |det Df | dx $